# How to import every Nth row of CSV file using python into script

Tags: python, csv, spline, pts, fusion360

I am using a script in fusion360 called importsplinecsv
I was wondering if it was possible to modify the script so that it would import one row every 10th row?
as the amount of rows that are being imported are very large and bloating.

if I could get some help that would be awesome.

here is the text

```
#Author-Autodesk Inc.
#Description-Import spline from csv file

import adsk.core, adsk.fusion, traceback
import io

def run(context):
    ui = None
    try:
        app = adsk.core.Application.get()
        ui  = app.userInterface
        # Get all components in the active design.
        product = app.activeProduct
        design = adsk.fusion.Design.cast(product)
        title = 'Import Spline csv'
        if not design:
            ui.messageBox('No active Fusion design', title)
            return
        
        dlg = ui.createFileDialog()
        dlg.title = 'Open CSV File'
        dlg.filter = 'Comma Separated Values (*.csv);;All Files (*.*)'
        if dlg.showOpen() != adsk.core.DialogResults.DialogOK :
            return
        
        filename = dlg.filename
        with io.open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
            points = adsk.core.ObjectCollection.create()
            line = f.readline()
            data = []
            while line:
                pntStrArr = line.split(',')
                for pntStr in pntStrArr:
                    try:
                        data.append(float(pntStr))
                    except:
                        break
            
                if len(data) >= 3 :
                    point = adsk.core.Point3D.create(data[0], data[1], data[2])
                    points.add(point)
                line = f.readline()
                data.clear()            
        if points.count:
            root = design.rootComponent
            sketch = root.sketches.add(root.xYConstructionPlane)
            sketch.sketchCurves.sketchFittedSplines.add(points)
        else:
            ui.messageBox('No valid points', title)            
            
    except:
        if ui:
            ui.messageBox('Failed:\n{}'.format(traceback.format_exc()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not used this library before but try:

```
for i, line in enumerate(f):
    if i%10==0:
        then your import command here
```

`f` is your filepointer
`i` will be the linenumber and `line` will be your line

```
 dlg = ui.createFileDialog()
    dlg.title = 'Open CSV File'
    dlg.filter = 'Comma Separated Values (*.csv);;All Files (*.*)'
    if dlg.showOpen() != adsk.core.DialogResults.DialogOK :
        return

    filename = dlg.filename
    with io.open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
        points = adsk.core.ObjectCollection.create()
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            if i%10==0:
                while line:
                    pntStrArr = line.split(',')
                    for pntStr in pntStrArr:
                        try:
                            data.append(float(pntStr))
                        except:
                            break

                    if len(data) >= 3 :
                        point = adsk.core.Point3D.create(data[0], data[1], data[2])
                        points.add(point)
                    line = f.readline()
                    data.clear()            
            if points.count:
                root = design.rootComponent
                sketch = root.sketches.add(root.xYConstructionPlane)
                sketch.sketchCurves.sketchFittedSplines.add(points)
            else:
                ui.messageBox('No valid points', title)            

except:
    if ui:
        ui.messageBox('Failed:\n{}'.format(traceback.format_exc()))
```

Comment: Hi Anarchy thanks for the reply! sorry to sound really stupid, but where should I input your added text.

Comment: okay take a look, but im really not sure how your library works so I cant really do much here